# How to test devise gem before_filter :authenticate_user! behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, tdd

I'm testing my app with **rspec**, and I need a hint with devise gem testing.
What is the best way for testing permissions to view some path.

For example I have this callback in my ProductController

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show, :index]
```

And I need somethisng like this

```
before (:each) do
    @user = User.create!({
      :name => 'Test User',
      :email => 'user@test.com',
      :password => 'pleaseletmein',
      :password_confirmation => 'pleaseletmein' 
      })
    sign_in @user
  end

 before ([:create, ....]) do
    sign_out @user if @user
  end

let(:valid_session) { {"warden.user.user.key" => session["warden.user.user.key"]} }
let(:un_valid_session) { {} }
.....

describe "create" do
  it "....." do
    get(:create, {}, un_valid_session)
    response.should redirect_to(root_path)
.....
```

Or share your way of testing this king of behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the rails3-bootstrap-devise-cancan project.
There is features folder, which contains pretty much you need
https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-bootstrap-devise-cancan/tree/master/features